# Why python code is still executed after I commented at eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I feel terrible about the error I come across!!

Now I am trying to run a google app engine application on eclipse. I installed google plugin for eclipse, PyDev and Aptana. When I use debug mode for my code, it looks very weird.

For example, **return statement is not being executed. However, sometimes, the commented code can be executed! It drives me crazy!!! What happens to this environment!!**
Here is one picture to show it ran commented code:
[image]

I can't analyze my code logically. The execution is totally out of order!!!

What should I do here? What are the reasons behind these strange situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally， I got the solution by myself.

After I added aptana studio eclipse plugin and reinstalled the google plugin for eclipse, the problem has been solved. It seems like only when apanta is used, then the step by step debugging for python in coursebuilder would work.

I think it may because the former debug environment is only for Java, but not works for python. So we have to install our own python debug tool, which is incorporated in apanta.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if your code is out of sync with the deployed version. Try redeploying your code and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your replying！ If it is out of sync, is there any way to synchronize the code in python?